# Install grub2 on another partition from Windows

Tags: windows, partitioning, installation, bootloader, grub2

I want to install `grub2` on my secondary Windows partition and chainload from primary Windows boot loader with `dd`. I can specify disk with `//./PHYSICALDRIVE0`. But how can I specify the partition?

Answer (score 1):

Found solution. You can use \.\C: to specify C:\ Drive so to install grub use "grub-install \.\C: --force" without quotes. --force is needed to overwrite a warning for not using first partition.